# Promise output varies between NodeJs and Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, promise

The following block of code executes differently between Node and the Browser.  Of course, different envs, different processing times, and race-condition possibility exists.  But per my understanding of Promises, this code should be consistent between environments.

I expect the Chrome/browser result.  I do not expect the NodeJs result.  I do not understand why each `newPromise`'s `then` chain is not completed *before* the `masterPromise`'s `then` chain continues.  In other words, because a new Promise is returned to the `masterPromise` promise-chain in a then `fn`, I would expect the new Promise's then-chain to finish out before the masterPromise promise-chain resumes.

I would love if someone could poke a hole in the following implementation, and explain why the NodeJs result is valid!

Using chrome 44 and node 12.6.

Ex:

```
'use strict';
var masterPromise = Promise.resolve();
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

// function returns a new promise that fulfills in 100ms
// it logs two bits of information--one pre-resolve, & one post-resolve.
// because a `.then` is registered immediately, before the promised is
// fulfilled, i would expect the post-resolve console.log to be logged before
// any other logging
var returnNewPromise = function(number) {
    var resolve;
    var newPromise = new Promise(function(r) { resolve = r; });
    newPromise.then(function() { console.log('registered ' + number + ' (verbatim, syncronous echo)'); });
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('registered ' + number);
        resolve();
    }, 100);
    return newPromise;
};

numbers.forEach(function(number) {
    var getChildPromise = function(number) {
        return returnNewPromise(number);
    };
    return masterPromise.then(function() {
        return getChildPromise(number);
    });
});
```

Node:

```
registered 1
registered 2
registered 3
registered 1 (verbatim, syncronous echo)
registered 2 (verbatim, syncronous echo)
registered 3 (verbatim, syncronous echo)
```

Chrome:

```
registered 1
registered 1 (verbatim, syncronous echo)
registered 2
registered 2 (verbatim, syncronous echo)
registered 3
registered 3 (verbatim, syncronous echo)
```

Comment: You'll need to add an elaboration of why, "based on your understanding of Promises", one or the other behavior should be expected. I think it's indeterminate, and that either of the two patterns is valid behavior under the relevant specifications.

Comment: @Pointy, fair enough!  Updated

Comment: @Pointy, I updated again to really get a narrower focus.  What syntactically induces the indeterminism, do you see?  A co-worker looked at this problem and thought it should be deterministic as well.  He, however, suffered the same issue I do, albeit he put together a great fiddle demonstrating the issue! https://jsfiddle.net/kgwouxg7/1/

Comment: It's not a **syntax** issue, it's a semantics iissue. I see absolutely no reason for it to be deterministic. The different event groups have no dependencies on one another, so the order of invocation should make absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand why each `newPromise`'s `then` chain is not
>   completed *before* the `masterPromise`'s `then` chain continues. A new
>   Promise is returned to the `masterPromise` promise-chain in a then
>   `fn`, so shouldn't it wait for that before the masterPromise
>   promise-chain resumes?

No. It seems your misunderstanding is about that "masterPromise chain": there is no such thing.
You've got one `masterPromise`, and then you've *chained three different `then` calls* from it. When the `masterPromise` resolves (which is immediately), it sees 3 callbacks and calls all of them in the order of their registration. It *does not care* what these callbacks do, whether they're asynchronous or not, and does not wait for their promise results. In your case, all of them create promises, and advance their subchain via them, but those 3 subchains are completely independent from each other.

Maybe fleshing out your code with more descriptive logging helps to understand what you were doing:

```
function delay(number) {
    console.log("creating promise for", number);
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('resolving promise with', number);
            resolve(number);
        }, 100);
    });
};
function result(n) {
    console.log("received", number);
}

var masterPromise = Promise.resolve();

masterPromise.then(function(){ delay(1).then(result); }); // chain 1
masterPromise.then(function(){ delay(2).then(result); }); // chain 2
masterPromise.then(function(){ delay(3).then(result); }); // chain 3
console.log("created chains");
```

The log you'll see here is

```
// .then chain 1    -------,
// .then chain 2    ------- \ -,
// .then chain 3    -------- \ -\ -,
created chains                |  |  |
                              |  |  | 3 then callbacks in the order they were registered
creating promise for 1      <´   |  |
// setTimeout 100   -----,       |  |
                          \     /   |
creating promise for 2     | <-´    |
// setTimeout 100   ------ |-,      /
                           |  \    /
creating promise for 3     |  | <-´
// setTimeout 100   ------ |- |-,
                           |  |  \
…                          |  |  | 3 timeout callbacks in the order they were scheduled
                           |  |  |
resolving promise with 1 <´   |  |
// resolve()                  |  |
[…]                           /  |
resolving promise with 2  <-´    |
// resolve()                     /
[…]                             /
resolving promise with 3   <---´
// resolve()
[…]
```

Here we can see 3 (independent) `resolve()` calls happening. They will each schedule their respective callback (`result`) *as soon as possible*. And here's the difference between node and Chrome: the former does execute timeout callbacks for the same time (they were scheduled at the same time with the same timeout) in the same tick, while Chrome uses separate ticks. So in node, "asap" is after the three callbacks, while in Chrome it is in between them. Both implementations are fine.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand why each newPromise then chain is not immediately executed upon its resolve

then-callbacks do not calls immediately.

```
var resolve;
new Promise(function (r) { resolve = r; })
    .then(function () { console.log(2); });
resolve();
console.log(1);
```

log:

```
1
2
```

Promise resolving behaves like `setTimeout` with zero delay.

**update:**

Comparison with `setTimeout` is not quite correct, because of limitations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimummaximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting
The similarity is in async kind of promises.

**update2:**

```
-----------+------------
wait       |  resolved
-----------+------------
timeout1   |             initial state
timeout2   |
-----------+------------
           | timeout1    after 100 ms
timeout2   |
-----------+------------
           | resolve1    then Chrome variant
           | timeout2
-----------+------------
           | timeout2    or Node variant
           | resolve1
-----------+------------
```

Both variants conform the specification. It seems that Chrome queues resolve callbacks before subsequent timeout callbacks.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason I think that a runtime could produce either result and be correct. Though one might imagine that `.then()` would just directly make a function call should the promise have been resolved already, that's not the way it's supposed to work: the callback is supposed to run with a clean stack, so it's invoked via some mechanism that's essentially like what this answer describes. Because of that, the browser may handle that before the pending timeouts, or it may not. (That's my opinion, but this answer is still right.)

Comment: Ya, this is news to me.  Thx.  Good to know it's a nextTick-possible operation.  But it still doesn't explain the following, which is against expectation.  'newPromise' gets returned inside of one of 'masterPromise's then's.  Shouldn't each of newPromise 's then's be executed before masterPromise's then-chain continues?  I feel like this contract isn't being honored.

Comment: @cdaringe no - why should that happen?

Comment: hey @Pointy, I believe because of this [this rule](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-57).  Right?  If X has a thenable, and that thenable returns a promise Y, then the promise chain adapts the state of Y, and should resolve out Y's then chain.  Suppose that Y's thenables return a promise Z.  In that case, Z should fulfill out, then any Y thens, and eventually anything left on X!

Comment: @cdaringe well that *might* be important, but what I'm not sure of is how the invocation of "then" callbacks is supposed to relate to the rest of the asynchronous environment.